# how to convert video into multiple fames using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, computer-vision, webassembly

New programmer here! I'm trying to convert a video into multiple jpegs (24fps) using FFmpeg.wasm and store it into an array. Honestly, I'm not sure what I'm doing but here's what I've done so far. *I'm writing this in React.

```
await ffmpeg.run(
  "-i", //? Input file
  `test.mp4`, //? name of = Input file
  "-vf", //? set filter
  "fps=24", //? set frame per sec
  "test-%04d.png" //? Output file
);

//* Read the result
const data = ffmpeg.FS("readFile", `test-0001.png`);
```

I need to store them in an array so I can do something with it after.
How should I go about it? Cheers!

**Update* Manage to find a workaround.**
Not too sure why I can't save it in jpeg though.

```
await ffmpeg.run(
      "-i", //? Input file
      `test.mp4`, //? name of = Input file
      "-vf", //? set filter
      "fps=24", //? set frame per sec
      "test-%05d.png" //? Output file
    );

    //* List entire directory
    const listDir = ffmpeg.FS("readdir", "/");

    //* Retain target files
    const fileData = (data) => {
      const arr = data.filter((fileName) => /^test-.*.png$/.test(fileName));
      return arr;
    };
    const targetFiles = fileData(listDir);
```

Comment: You are asking multiple questions: 1) *"how to convert video into multiple fames using FFMPEG?"* 2) *"I need to store them in an array so I can do something with it after. How should I go about it? "* Do you need help with #1 or #2? Nobody has answered because it is unclear what you need help with.

Comment: Hi @llogan, Thanks for the feedback. I will craft my message better next time. I manage to work around it but I'm sure there's is a better way around this. I've updated my post with my code.